# VBScript InputBox and Help Files

Tags: vbscript, chm

I am creating a script for my team at work, and I've been requested to make a help file that can be launched from the input boxes directly.  I know that the InputBox function can take a help file as an argument, so I created a .chm file with all the necessary information.

In a test script, I have the following code:

```
sTest = InputBox("Test", "Test", , , , "Hardware_Project_Wizard_Help.chm", 1)
```

The input box shows up when I run the script, and the Help button is visible.  However, when the help and support window opens up, it says:

> "The Help for this program was created in Windows Help format, which
>   depends on a feature that isn't included in this version of Windows.
>   However, you can download a program that will allow you to view Help
>   created in the Windows Help format. "

Based on all the documentation for InputBox, it seems that it is expecting a .hlp file.  I would like to avoid having to re-make the help file and asking my whole team to download a program that will allow them to view it.  Is there anyway to use a .chm, like the one I have created?

Comment: Good question - MS has been phasing out hlp format for along time now but appear to be in no rush to change the help file format used in MsgBox or InputBox. The only option I can see is to build your own input box - some ideas might be generated here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282463/put-an-image-as-the-background-of-an-input-box

Comment: dbmitch thanks for the edit and the advice!  I think building my own input box is a bit outside the scope of the project at the moment "I'm just going to put text in there pointing to our server location).  But it will definitely be worth it in future iterations of the script!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching, I managed to find [one website](http://microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript.narkive.com/m9HV7VjF/problem-opening-chm-help-file-from-msgbox-inputbox) that mentioned the .hlp format is the only one accepted by InputBox.  I'm not sure that you could consider it a reliable source, but taking dbmitch's comment into account, it seems like a .chm file cannot be used with InputBox.