# VBScipt MsgBox help file not opening

Tags: vbscript, wsh, chm

I have written a VBScript program, and there is a helpfile I am using that allows the user to change settings. In the program, there is a line that goes like this:

```
startPrompt=MsgBox("prompt", 32+4, "title", "Panels/Help.chm", 0)
```

For some reason, the help file just doesn't open when I click "Help".

Supposedly, using 0 as the context leads to the default page of the helpfile. I've also tried using 1001 (the actual context id of a page), and it doesn't work either.

A little more background might be helpful. The script runs from a .wsf file, and a folder called Panels is in the same directory. Inside the Panels folder is the helpfile and the Subscripts folder, which holds the code of the .wsf file in different .txt files.

If it is really necessary to see all the code of the program, I can put it up for download.

Comment: Looks like VBScript's MsgBox function only supports the old help files format (.hlp) and doesn't support chm help files, unlike VBA and VB6. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50258344/4934172).